# How to make a read-only property become writable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reflection, google-chrome-extension, properties, prototype

I'm trying to turn an object's property writable. 
It's a complex third party object, so I'm not able to make a constructor for it.

So far, I've tried something like this. Is there any other way I could accomplish that?

I tried to replace the property in the prototype, and create a wrapper for that, but the "setter" is undefined when it runs.

```
var originalProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(TheObjectClass.prototype, 'theProperty');                

delete TheObjectClass.prototype.theProperty;        

//the following is pseudo(is it?) code: 
Object.defineProperty(TheObjectClass.prototype, 'theProperty', {
    get: function() {return originalProperty.get.call(this);},
    set: function(val) {originalProperty.set.call(this,val);}
});
```

Does anyone have an interesting idea about what to do to accomplish the idea?

By the way, if it's possible to isolate a property like that, would it be right to use "call" or "apply"? What would be the correct way?

PS: I'm trying that in a Chrome Extension, if that matters.

Comment: What do you mean by "illegal"?

Comment: Also, `TheObject.prototype` looks pretty suspicious - that's not how you access the prototype chain of an object. Constructor functions have `prototype` properties, but not instances.

Comment: "Illegal invocation" is the error message I get from trying that. I'm used to working on the prototype. "TheObject" is not an instance there.

Comment: So "TheObject" is not an object instance, but an object constructor?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could post what `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(TheObject.prototype.theProperty)` looks like.

Comment: The property descriptor also brings back an "illegal invocation".

Comment: what exactly is this object? what environment?

Comment: @Daniel You should use `var originalProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(TheObjectClass.prototype, 'theProperty');` instead of `var originalProperty = TheObjectClass.prototype.theProperty;`.

Comment: Thanks @RobW, that solves the illegal part. But then the "set" is undefined.

Comment: @Daniel Of course not. What setter would you expect for a read-only property?